# node throws module.js:340 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I'm using the MEANstack for a project and hit up this error when trying to load the model from seed.js:

```
module.js:340
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '..api/callout/callout.model'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\onemore\server\config\seed.js:12:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Proof of existence of the file:

```
Directory of C:\onemore\server\api\callout

01/27/2015  03:47 PM    <DIR>          .
01/27/2015  03:47 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/27/2015  03:27 PM             2,267 callout.controller.js
01/27/2015  03:47 PM               308 callout.model.js
01/27/2015  03:39 PM               602 index.js
```

Since I have other models that I set up the exact same way and they are working, I can't explain what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace that path with `../api/callout/callout.model`

Comment: Thanks, my mistake, I just couldn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably `../api/.......`  rather than `..api/........`

Also, make sure that the relative path is correct.

Comment: oh god, I'm blind. Thanks for the quick answer